# JHipster - Change default page to some entity page

Tags: java, angular, jhipster

I'm trying to create a small application with jhipster and now i'm trying to change the default landing page (/) to a specific entity page.

There's a way to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to locate where Jhipster app associate the landing page with home.component. I know that i can change home page with the content of mine entity page, but i think that is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty route that redirects to your entity? See http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the default home.route.ts to this, and achivied the expected result.

Thanks for the attention

```
    import { Route } from '@angular/router';

    import { UserRouteAccessService } from '../shared';
    import { HomeComponent } from './';

    export const HOME_ROUTE: Route = {
           path: '',  redirectTo: 'pessoas', pathMatch: 'full' 
    };
```